# MikroTik RouterOS 5.18 Does not connect to internet after restart

Tags: routing, dhcp, internet, mikrotik, pppoe

I am setting up a RouterOS on an x86 machine. The router is configure and is connected to internet via PPPoE internet connection.
I am distributing it to 5 PCs and a Router via RouterOS PC.
The setup is working flawlessly until the PC is restarted when it looses its internet connection. I know that the IP for PPPoE is provided is Dynamically. Hence the router looses internet connection when connection is restarted and it gets a new ip.

now the main question: how can i make it work with a dynamic ip. what changes should i make in the Routes.

Regards

Comment: can no one help?? :( still stuck with it

Answer (score 0):

In your srcnat rule are you setting your action to srcnat and setting a specific IP address? If so you might change the action to masquerade which will automatically choose an IP to use for NAT.

Comment: Thanx for your reply. I had done this, it now reconfigures itself. If it does not then i edit the routes to the correct ip. :D